# Using foreach to select the correct index in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been having trouble with this problem for a bit now. I use forEach to loop through an array, and I want the correct page to render with the corresponding index when I click on the component. Right now my issue is that I loop through my array, but I am not able to return the correct index, only the first one in the array. I want the `startPage` prop on the `Pages` component to render to correct index from my `newNum` variable.

```
const itemId = this.props.navigation.getParam('pk');

let newArray = this.props.moment.filter(item => {
  return item.trip == itemId
});
console.log('getting moment fromt trip')
let num = Object.keys(this.props.trip[0].moments)
let newNum = num.forEach((number, index) => {
  console.log(number)
  return number
})

return (
  // <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#F0F5F7'}} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
  <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#F0F5F7'}}>
  <HeaderMomentComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
  <Pages indicatorColor="salmon" startPage={newNum}>
    {newArray.map((item, index) => {
      console.log('this is the index')
      console.log(index)
      return(
        <MomentContent
          name={item.name}
          place={item.place}
          description={item.description}
          tags={item.tags}
          key={index}
        />
      )
    })}
  </Pages>
</View>
);
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. Are you looking for `map`?

Comment: It's difficult to help you without seeing more context. Where is `newArray` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. And @Li357, I already tried map. I don't believe it will work for this use case.

Comment: @ChristianLessard It doesn't do anything even if you were to add `map` because you're just returning the element. You would be getting the exact same array. What's the goal with `newNum`?

Comment: newNum is supposed to be the current index when I navigate to the MomentContent component. StartPage is the prop that says what index it should start on. Currently the index it is starting on is only the first. I want the index to correspond to the correct MomentContent component that I click on. For instance, if there are two components rendered through MomentContent, one being A and one being B, If i click on B it shows me A.

Comment: Instead of `forEach` why don't you use `reduce` and return an object where the prop is the `moment` and the index the value. Then just use that in your component to get the index.

    var arr = ['moment1', 'moment2']
    var result = arr.reduce((result, current, index, array) => {
        result[current] = index
        return  result
    }, {})

    console.log(result)  // {moment1: 0, moment2: 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach#Return_value) (Mozilla Developer Network), return value of `forEach` is `undefined`.

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a `newNum` value.

```
let newNum = num.map((number, index) => {
  // Some logic to get a new number...
  return number
})
```